# Getting an error message back from Parse.Cloud.beforeSave to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

Does anyone know how to get an error back from the beforeSave function. For example if my beforeSave function looks like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("UserData", function(request, response) {
var currentSaveVersion = request.object.get("SaveVersion");


var query = new Parse.Query("UserData");
query.equalTo("Username", request.object.get("Username"));
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      var lastSaveVersion = -1000;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        lastSaveVersion = results[i].get("SaveVersion");
      }

      if(currentSaveVersion == (lastSaveVersion + 1)) {
        console.log("UserData BeforeSave success");
        response.success({ "success": "Successful save" });
      } else {
          var errorMessage = "UserData BeforeSave SaveVersion Mismatch";
          console.log(errorMessage);
          //we need to respond with success to unity, but examine the return value for the error
          response.success({ "code": "SaveMismatch", "message": errorMessage });
      }

    },
    error: function(user,error) {
      var errorMessage = "UserData BeforeSave Could not look up lastSaveVersion";
      console.log(errorMessage);
      response.error(errorMessage);
      if (error.code >= 200 && error.code < 300) {
        // Unity Hack
        response.success({ "code": error.code, "message": error.message });
      } else {
        response.error({ "code": error.code, "message": error.message });
      }
    }
});

});
```

Unfortunately Unity believes that it is successful, but I cannot get the return value back because the System.Threading.Task class does not have the Return property that is mentioned in a related post [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/unity-sign-up-user-unusable-since-no-202-error).

Here is the Unity side cloud that I'm trying to use to see that there might be an error sent in the response.success message... here is an example that does not compile:

System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = myUserData.SaveAsync();

```
    while (!task.IsCompleted) yield return null;

    if (task.IsCanceled){
        // the save was cancelled.
        Debug.Log ("ParseManager.cs saveUserData, task cancelled");
    } else if (task.IsFaulted) {
        // The login failed. Check task.Exception to see why.
        Debug.Log ("ParseManager.cs saveUserData, task exception: ");
        debugLogException(task);

    } else {
        // the object was saved successfully.
        Debug.Log ("ParseManager.cs saveUserData, save successful ");
        Debug.Log ("Task result: " + task.Result);
        newUserSaveNeeded = false;
    }
```

Note that System.Threading.Tasks.Task does not have a Result property. What is the correct C# type returned by SaveAsync that would allow me to see the result?

Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is a couple of things going on here.

Firstly there is a known bug in Unity's stack that means that Parse can't get detailed error messages from the cloud:

https://www.parse.com/questions/unity-sdk-handling-errors

So it doesn't matter what error you return back from your cloud code, all you will get in Unity is a generic error without an error message (yes this is incredibly frustrating but I heard that when Unity gets its new compiler this will be fixed).

Secondly, you can return just a string in your error message and it should return just fine:

```
response.error("something bad happened!");
```

I always write unit tests for my cloud code in a C# Unit Test project using the Parse.com .NET SDK which does support custom error messages (and async / await), something like the following:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SaveUserTests
{
    [SetUp]
    public async void Init()
    {
        TestingHelpers.InitParse();
        ParseUser.LogOut();
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(ExpectedMessage = "Must supply a player name when creating a new user")]
    public async void RequiresPlayerName()
    {
        var user = new GameUser()
        {
            Username = TestingHelpers.GetRandomUserEmail(),
            Password = "a"
        };
        await user.SignUpAsync();
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(ExpectedMessage = "Username and email address must be equal")]
    public async void UsernameAndEmailMustBeEqual()
    {
        var user = new GameUser()
        {
            Username = TestingHelpers.GetRandomUserEmail(),
            Email = TestingHelpers.GetRandomUserEmail(),
            Password = "a",
            PlayerName = "Test User"
        };
        await user.SignUpAsync();
    }
}
```

That way I can be sure that cloud code is doing what it should be doing.

BTW my cloud code for saving a user looks like the following (written in Typescript):

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("_User", (request, response) => {

    // Must have a player name
    if (request.object.get("playerName") == null)
        return response.error("Must supply a player name when creating a new user");

    // Email and username must equal
    if (request.object.get("email") != request.object.get("username"))
        return response.error("Username and email address must be equal");

    // All done
    response.success();
});
```

Now, I have recently run into an issue that I havent been able to replicate in a simple example where the Parse.com Unity SDK seems to be consuming the error returned from the cloud code and instead returning a success when it was infact been an error!

The is obviously incredibly bad and shouldn't happen and as I say I wasn't able to replicate it in a simple example but if you are experiencing the same thing then please do write a bug report and submit it to parse to get fixed.

My suspicion (after decompiling the ParseSDK with ILSpy) is that Parse itself is throwing an exception which is being caught by a handler somewhere.

My workaround for the problem was to check to see if the objectId had been set (I was creating an Object and thus the objectId hadnt been set yet) and if it hadn't, return an error from my service. A nasty hack but it works for now.

Anyways I hope that helps!